# Spring Cloud and Eureka: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for ACCOUNTS-SERVICE

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I've been trying to create microservices with Spring Cloud and Eureka.

For now I have a server that picks up 2 microservices: ACCOUNTS-SERVICE and WEB-SERVICE

```
[nio-1111-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance ACCOUNTS-SERVICE/192.168.0.13:accounts-service:2222 with status UP (replication=false)
[nio-1111-exec-4] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance WEB-SERVICE/192.168.0.13:web-service:3333 with status UP (replication=false)
```

This is my web service:

```
package eu.epitech.jug.services.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

/**
 * Created by sadzeih on 12/9/16.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters=false)
public class WebServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Will configure using web-server.yml
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "web-server");
        SpringApplication.run(WebServer.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebAccountService accountService()
    {
        return new WebAccountService("http://ACCOUNTS-SERVICE");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebAccountController accountController() {
        return new WebAccountController(accountService());
    }
}
```

In WebAccountService there is this:

```
package eu.epitech.jug.services.web;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


/**
 * Created by sadzeih on 12/9/16.
 */
@Service
public class WebAccountService {
    @Autowired
    @LoadBalanced
    protected RestTemplate restTemplate;

    protected String serviceUrl;

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebAccountService.class.getName());

    public WebAccountService(String serviceUrl) {
        this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl.startsWith("http") ?
                serviceUrl : "http://" + serviceUrl;
    }

    public Account getByEmail(String email) {
        logger.info("serviceurl = " + serviceUrl);
        return restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl
                + "/accounts/{email}", Account.class, email);
    }

}
```

And in the controller it's just a route. But this happens:

```
[nio-3333-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for ACCOUNTS-SERVICE] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for ACCOUNTS-SERVICE
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276) ~[spring-retry-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-retry-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:68) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4e9ed0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.captureUrlTemplate(RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.java:33) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da8e3778.getForObject(<generated>) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at eu.epitech.jug.services.web.WebAccountService.getByEmail(WebAccountService.java:30) ~[classes!/:na]
    at eu.epitech.jug.services.web.WebAccountController.getAccount(WebAccountController.java:27) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar!/:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

You can find the code here: https://github.com/Sadzeih/microservices-test

I've been trying to find the problem, but I definitely can't.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are your dependencies?

Comment: Here is my [gradle.build](https://github.com/Sadzeih/microservices-test/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: I'm unsure how all of that will work. You are missing `compile ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')`

Comment: I still get the same thing

Comment: Having all three projects with the same dependencies may have adverse effects

Answer (score 6):

I believe `@LoadBalanced` in `WebAccountService.restTemplate` is not needed.
I also think the service name being used in:

```
public Account getByEmail(String email) {
    logger.info("serviceurl = " + serviceUrl);
    return restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl
                + "/accounts/{email}", Account.class, email);
}
```

might be incorrect. Could you paste you bootstrap and application properties files? It might need to be a key mapped to the service name located in one of these files, something like:

```
the-demo-registration-api-1:
   ribbon:
     # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
     DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: demo-registration-api-1
```

then using http://the-demo-registration-api-1 instead of the service name.

I recently blogged about Microservices Registration and Discovery using Spring Cloud, Eureka, Ribbon and Feign at http://tech.asimio.net/2016/11/14/Microservices-Registration-and-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Ribbon-and-Feign.html#load-balancing-requests-using-resttemplate-and-loadbalanced where different options to send requests to registered services are discussed such as `load-balancing requests using Spring Cloud Feign`, `load-balancing requests using RestTemplate AND @LoadBalanced` and `load-balancing requests using RestTemplate AND LoadBalancerClient`.

Hopefully it can answer your question.

Updated:

WebServer service would need `Ribbon` configuration so that it can find the Account service in the registry:

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8000/eureka/
  instance:
    ...
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}

the-accounts-service:
  ribbon:
    # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
    DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: accounts-service

    #listOfServers: localhost:${SERVER.PORT}
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList

    # Interval to refresh the server list from the source (ms)
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 30000
```

Comment: Also, I tried doing the key mapped to the service as you showed, and it produced the same error with `the-account-service` instead

Comment: The ability of `RestTemplate` to work with service names is provided by `Ribbon`. I couldn't find any `Ribbon` configuration in your yml and properties files. Something like:

`
the-demo-registration-api-1:
  ribbon:
    # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
    DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: demo-registration-api-1

    #listOfServers: localhost:${SERVER.PORT}
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList

    # Interval to refresh the server list from the source (ms)
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 30000
`

in WebServer

Comment: @Sadzeih
I have edited my initial answer to include `Ribbon` configuration needed in WebServer service

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your answer but still getting the same error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for the-account-service`. You can see the changes in the repository

Comment: When you open http://localhost:1111/eureka in a browser, do you see ACCOUNTS-SERVICE and WEB-SERVICE there?

Comment: @Sadzeih
The only thing I can think off the top of my head is that WebServer service is not fetching the registry. Could you add `eureka.client.fetchRegistry: true` to its yml file while keeping all the changes I have mentioned before?

Comment: did that too, same result.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by removing  @LoadBalanced  from the bean

Comment: Wow..this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

So after many changes, I found the solution to my problem.
I simply separated the microservices into different modules and everything pretty much worked.
Don't try to make multiple microservices into one module, you'll only get yourself into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in application.properties of WebServer
the value spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled = false

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks!